# Database randomly deletes itself every so often

Tags: android, database

I have a normal SQLite database in my app, managed through my own ContentProvider and implemented via SQLiteOpenHelper.

On the Droid only, every few weeks or so, the database just disappears. I have several users who wrote me about that, and I've seen it myself too now. I added some debug info (hard to repro when you only see it every few weeks), and in one instance, it just happened inbetween widget updates - first, the widget is displayed and shows the data just fine, the next time, the SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate is called.

The app itself does some multi-threaded shenanigans, but all ContentProvider implementations have the synchronized keyword, all access to the database is via the content provider, and in the instance described above, there is no multi-threading going on (the app itself hadn't been running, just the widget).

And again, this is only on the Droid. I've never seen it on the G1. I never close the database, but it being a content provider, it sounds like I'm not supposed to do that in the first place (I remember hackbod saying that the idea is that the OS will close the app's process when necessary, which will automatically close the database).

Any ideas?

Comment: How easy is this to reproduce?  Do you have any logcat output from when it happened?

Comment: Extremely hard to reproduce - it just randomly happens. I have a widget for my app, so one day I turn my phone on and see that the widget shows there are no records.

Some users report that they start the app, and there are no records. Since I have no idea when it happens, I have no logcat output. I did add a logfile to my app. All I can see is that the widget updates, does a query and gets results. An hour later, the widget updates again, does a query, the content provider tries to grab the database which implicitly calls onCreate, indicating there was no database present.

Comment: Might be the same root cause as http://b.android.com/5669 (which does not yet have a resolution).  That bug has 528 comments, and so far only 1 partially-useful bug report, so I was hoping you might have a way to make it happen or a full log.

Comment: Thanks fadden! That does indeed look related. And I really hate that every schmuck on the street can make unmoderated replies to bug reports, now there are 520 "me too" comments that I really don't want to sift through.

My only guess is that this is related to multi-threaded database/content-provider access. It's suspicious though that it only seems to happen on the Droid (both 2.0 and 2.1). Btw, which comment has the useful bug report?

Comment: There was so much noise in the bug that the guy sent it to me privately. :-)  It showed an entry in the event log (logcat -b events) that indicated database corruption.  The verbose debug log had scrolled off already so we couldn't see any detail messages, but at least we got confirmation that the problem was due to database corruption.

Comment: That sounds even more like unsafe multi-threaded access to the database file. Again, I put "synchronized" around each one of the ContentProvider overrides (which are the only files that can access the database). But how about the case where two threads try to access the database at the same time while it's not opened yet? I wonder if that could cause the database object to be created twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, SQLiteDatabase has locking enabled by default (`SQLiteDatabase.setLockingEnabled`). In my app, I explicitly turn it on after opening, and added some other more paranoid synchronization to make sure multiple threads can't access the database at the same time, and that seems to have fixed it.

I'm still curious as to why this problem only ever occured on the Motorola Droid, and I had this hunch that this phone has locking disabled by default, but that sounds a bit weird - the Droid, after all, is one of the phones with almost no customization by the manufacturer at all.

In any case, explicitly enabling locking and proper synchronization did the trick for me.